# c# mvc 5 display model text from list based on id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model:

```
public class Model
{
   public string Id { get; set }
   public List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my view I have:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.Where(t=>t.Value ==  item.Id).Select(t=>t.Text))
}
```

Basically the Items property will have something like this:

```
Value = 1
Text = "Somethnig"

Value = 2
Text = "Somethnig else"

Value = 3
Text = "Somethnig else in here"
```

The Id property will hold the Value of the item, which can be `1, 2, 3 and so forth`.

How can I display in my view the Text of the item rather then the Value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want acces to the Items lists, try this.

```
@foreach (SelectListItem item in Model.Items)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(item.Text)
}
```

Now if `var item` is an `object` of `Model` DatatType then try this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Items.Where(t=>t.Value ==  item.Id)[0].Text)
}
```

**Note:** that if there is not a object in the list that complies with expression `t.Value ==  item.Id` there not going to be an object in index 0, and for this reason will give you an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
value: item.Id
Text: item.Text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is my model in my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iMBQ.png)

I'm working on .net MVC3

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `examen_paco`.`consola` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `examen_paco`.`juegos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `examen_paco`.`juegos` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  `consola_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```

I made a query that shows me the list of console table.

Now I want you to give me click on a console game show list containing the id belonging to each console.

I'm using C# within the controller.